# Drive/Partition and unique drive ID in Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, drive

Alright, I'm looking to create a program that can take a unique drive ID (serial number?), and put it into a database where it associates the ID with some files. If I want to find a file on something like a flashdrive (which can change drive letter), I attach the flashdrive, my program scans for it's unique ID, looks up the files based on something like a stl::map, and converts the unique ID to a drive letter.

The program would also need to recognise partitions as well (obviously), so maybe uniqueid+partitionnumber on the device.

Any ideas on how I can go about this? I'm looking at the source code for EnumDisk (Windows code sample) but the included demo .exe doesn't seem to work under Windows 7 (said it was compatible without rebuilding from source).

Any takers?

P.S. I get this error from ENumDisk.exe 
'CreateFile failed with error: 5'

P.S.S. Oh, and I want the program to be able to scan drives that are from other filesystems and get *their* serial IDs. I know that's a tall order but this is my eventual aim.

Answer (score 4):

You're in luck - Windows (specifically the Mount Manager) maintains just such a database of unique volume identifiers.  Have a look at the [Volume Management APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example, you can use [GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364994%28VS.85%29.aspx) to obtain a unique identifier for a given mount point (including drive letters) even removable volumes.  Alternately, since a volume can have multiple mount points, you can use [FindFirst/NextVolumeMountpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the mountpoints for given volume id (GUID).

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Error 5 is access denied. This means you are most likely running as non-admin. If you are trying to open a physical drive you may be able to get away by setting the "dwDesiredAccess" parameter to 0. It may succeed in opening the device, but later operations may fail, depending on what API functions you use the returned handle with.

As for getting partition information look at  IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365173(v=vs.85).aspx and IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365179(v=vs.85).aspx

You will be able to gather all partitions, even those belonging to filesystems Windows doesn't recognize.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I'm currently trying to use STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY into DeviceIoControl to get back a STORAGE_DEVICE_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER, which will contain the serial number.

My problem is, in the MSDN it states that the STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY
is in winioctl.h. I'm using CodeBlocks with the latest MinGW, but it keeps saying:

error: 'STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY' was not declared in this scope.

So I looked in winioctl.h in the MinGW include directory, and there was no STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY. Has anyone stumbled across this problem before?

Comment: You should grab the latest WDK.

Comment: I worked that part out. MinGW is a bugger and doesn't have all the defines and GUIDs.

Comment: Note for the future, `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT` is superseded by  `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntdddisk/ni-ntdddisk-ioctl_disk_get_drive_layout_ex